# strange content type in drupal

Tags: drupal-6, content-type, drupal-taxonomy

i want to have a content type for my properties. let's name it 'my properties'.

and i have a taxonomy called 'my properties type' that contains 'books,shoes,clothes'.

the form for adding properties change on taxonomy selected item,because each of its type have different fields.

is it possible to have such content type in drupal ??

Answer (score 0):

The solution within Drupal is to create separate content types for each property type.  However, you can easily write some jquery to show/hide fields when taxonomy field is modified:

```
        $('#your-taxonomy-dropdown').change(function() {
           if($(this).val() == 'book') {
              $('#field1').hide();
              $('#field2').show();
           }        
        });
```